# What generation i5 processor is required for flutter development on windows 10

Tags: android, flutter, mobile

I am expecting to begin flutter development on windows 10, so i need to know What generation i5 processor is required for flutter development, how many cores should i have in my processor ,please be kind to mention other requirements also like ram, storage, vga etc..(i need to run a android emulator )

i asked this in few groups, some say 4th generation processor is enough and some say it needs a 8th  generation+ processor, so i'm confused..

Answer (score 0):

4th generation can be enough, but it can get kinda hard and slow to develop. in my opinion CPU and ram are more important to develop faster and easier. like it is fine to have 8GB ram but you can't open 2 other apps or open 10 tabs on Chrome. so you need at least `16 GB of ram`. CPU can be something like `i5 10600K`. storage doesn't matter really. of course, every thing will be faster on SSDs but the emulator needs something like 16 GB at max. and for VGA if you don't have any, it will use your CPU (software acceleration)